# Voice over not narrating dialog open and exit dialog

Tags: accessibility, voiceover

When I open a web dialog using voice over, then it doesn't narrates dialog box open and diolog box exit upon closing it.
When I tried the same thing using chromevox, it narrated open and close of dialog box.
Is this some bug with voice over? Or am I missing something here?
I have added aria-labelledby, aria-describedby and role to the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Are you moving the focus into the dialog when it opens?  If the focus is still on the main part of the page that opened the dialog, then there's nothing for the screen reader to announce.

Follow the [dialog design pattern](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#dialog_modal) and note especially the [NOTE](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#h-note-6) about initial keyboard focus.